# Display First and Last string entries stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable `MyVar` with values stored in it. For example:

```
MyVar="123, 234, 345, 456"
```

Each entry in the variable is separated by a coma as in the example above.
I want to be able to pick the first and last entry from this variable, i.e `123` and `456` respectively.

Any idea how I can achieve this from the command prompt terminal ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
MyVar="123, 234, 345, 456"
first=$(echo "$MyVar" | sed 's/,.*//')
last=$(echo "$MyVar" | sed 's/.*, //')
echo $first $last
```

**Explanation:**

- To obtain the first string, we replace everything after & including
  the first comma with nothing (empty string).
- To obtain the last string, we replace everything before & including the last comma with nothing (empty string).

Comment: Hi @costaparas, could I add the same to a Jenkins Pipeline script? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You can have a multi-line shell script in a pipeline, like [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/).

Answer (score 8):

Using bash substring removal:

```
$ echo ${MyVar##*,}
456
$ echo ${MyVar%%,*}
123
```

Also:

```
$ echo ${MyVar/,*,/,}
123, 456
```

More for example here:

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

**Edit**: Above kind of expects the substrings to be separated by commas only. See comments where @costaparas gloriously demonstrates a case with `,` .

Comment: Caveat with `${MyVar##*,}`: it will contain a leading space (concealed here since its passed unquoted to the `echo`). Could change to `${MyVar##*, }`.

Comment: Hi @James, could I add the same to a Jenkins Pipeline script? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @SD4 Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Jenkins but if you gut Bash running there I don't see why not. SInce 99 % of IT is crash and burn I mean test and see anyway I'd just go ahead and test. :D

Comment: Oh Okay sure! 
Any idea how the same can be achieved using the windows cmd.exe?

Comment: @SD4 None, sorry. Last time I (really) used any .exe was back in -93 and I believe it was Windows 3.11.

Answer (score 4):

Using bash array:

```
IFS=', ' arr=($MyVar)
echo ${arr[0]} ${arr[-1]}
```

Where `${arr[0]}` and `${arr[-1]}` are your first and last respective values. Negative index requires bash 4.2 or later.

Answer (score 3):

You could try following also with latest BASH version, by sending variable values into an array and then retrieve first and last element, keeping all either values in it saved in case you need them later in program etc.

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$MyVar"
echo "${array[0]}"
123
echo "${array[-1]}"
456
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk alternative:

```
awk -F "(, )" '{ print $1" - "$NF }' <<< $MyVar
```

Set the field separator to command and a space. Print the first field and the last field (NF) with " - " in between.